# Bijective morphism that is biregular on every irreducible component

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-varieties

Consider a morphism $f:X\to Y$ between two (quasi-projective, say) algebraic varieties. Let $X_1,\dots,X_n$ be the irreducible components of $X$. Suppose that $f$ is a bijection, that $f(X_1),\dots,f(X_n)$ are the irreducible components of $Y$ and that, furthermore, $f:X_i\to f(X_i)$ is an isomorphism for every $i$. I know that, in general, this does not imply that $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic. My question is under which reasonable additional conditions $f$ must indeed be an isomorphism.

In case it helps, in my setting $X$ and $Y$ are projective and their components are normal. (Could these conditions already be sufficient?)

Comment: Maybe I'm just suffering from a failure of imagination here, but can you remind me of the counterexample for why the conditions you have listed don't give an isomorphism?

Comment: @KReiser Not completely sure this is the simplest example but let $Y\subset \mathbb A^2$ be the union of the line $y=0$ and the curve $y-x^2=0$ and $X\subset\mathbb A^3$ be the union of the line  $y=z=0$ and the curve $z-x=y-x^2=0$. Then $f$ can be chosen as the projection from $\mathbb A^3$ onto the plane $z=0$.

Comment: Why are those two not isomorphic?

Comment: @RghtHndSd The function on $Y$ that is $x$ on the line and 0 on the quadric is not regular but its pullback is regular on $X$.

Comment: Oh, right! Thanks for the reminder. Another example which might be easier to think about is three lines intersecting at a point in the plane versus the three coordinate axes in $\Bbb A^3$: you can look at the tangent space at the intersection points to see they're not isomorphic, but all the irreducible components are just lines. If you're willing to upgrade "components are normal" to "$X$ or $Y$ is normal" in your situation, then you do indeed have an isomorphism. Is this in the vein of what you're looking for?

Comment: @KReiser Yes, thanks, I knew there must be some sort of simple example with linear subspaces! As for normality... Well, if "normal" implies "every connected component is irreducible", then this is not my case at all, unfortunately.

Comment: If you're interested in a specific case, you might want to edit that in to the problem - you'll get better help that way.

Comment: @KReiser At this point I'm not sure what else is worth mentioning other than the irreducible components being normal and projective. I'm kind of looking for a general fact of this form, I guess, one that would use as few assumptions as possible. To give you a feel for the situation: my $X$ is actually a union of torus orbit closures in a normal projective toric variety. But I really don't want to make this part of the question, this is not a question about toric geometry.